# Summing number from two tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using phpMyAdmin and I have two tables:

**___SalesTaxes**

```
|--------|----------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_Name | STX_Amount |
|--------|----------|------------|
|      1 |    Tax 1 |       5.00 |
|      2 |    Tax 2 |      13.50 |
|--------|----------|------------|
```

**___BillableDatas**

```
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|----------|---------------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId | BIL_Date   | BIL_Status | BIL_Rate | BIL_ApplicableTaxes |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|----------|---------------------|
|      1 |             2 | 2018-03-06 | notcharged |   100.00 |                   1 |
|      2 |             2 | 2018-03-07 | notcharged |   105.00 |                 1,2 |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|----------|---------------------|
```

---

I want to list per day a list of the billable things in `___BillableDatas` depending the status of the thing (charged vs notcharged).

So something like this:

```
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|    Date    | BIL_Sum_Charged | BIL_Sum_Notcharged | Taxes_ForCharged | TaxesForNotCharged |
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
| 2018-03-06 |            0.00 |             100.00 |             0.00 |               5.00 |
| 2018-03-07 |            0.00 |             105.00 |             0.00 |              19.42 |
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
```

---

What I have actually:

```
SELECT b.BIL_Date, 
ifnull(sum(case when b.BIL_Status = "charged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end), 0) 
as BIL_Sum_Charged, 
ifnull(sum(case when b.BIL_Status = "notcharged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end), 0) 
as BIL_Sum_Notcharged,
ifnull(sum(case when b.BIL_status = "charged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end), 0) 
as STX_TAX_Charged,
ifnull(sum(case when b.BIL_status = "notcharged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end), 0) 
as STX_TAX_NotCharged
FROM ___BillableDatas b
INNER JOIN ___SalesTaxes s
ON FIND_IN_SET(s.STX_id, b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
WHERE b.BIL_HotelId='cus_CNHLMiMOzP5cuM' 
AND b.BIL_BookingId='2' 
GROUP BY b.BIL_Date 
ORDER BY b.BIL_Date 
ASC
```

---

Problem with this query is I do not have the right sum for `BIL_Sum_Charged` and `BIL_Sum_NotCharged`.

I've `210` whereas I should have `105` for `BIL_Sum_Notcharged` for 2018-03-07.

Where is my error please ?

Please see the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1208e/11

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: When you do a SELECT * and no "group by" you will get 3 lines and not two because of the tax ids 1 and 2, so when you do the sum, it will sum the 2 lines

Comment: Ok, but how can I get the desired output please because actually my report is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposal, not sure it's the best solution :

I get ride of the IFNULL, they won't be useful. I divide by the number of "," +1

```
SELECT b.BIL_Date,
SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "charged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") ) ))
   as BIL_Sum_Charged, 
 SUM(case when b.BIL_Status = "notcharged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end
 / (1 + LENGTH(b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes, ",", "") )))
      as BIL_Sum_Notcharged,
  SUM(case when b.BIL_status = "charged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end) 
      as STX_TAX_Charged,
  SUM(case when b.BIL_status = "notcharged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end) 
     as STX_TAX_NotCharged
 FROM ___BillableDatas b
 INNER JOIN ___SalesTaxes s
 ON FIND_IN_SET(s.STX_id, b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
 WHERE b.BIL_HotelId='cus_CNHLMiMOzP5cuM' 
 AND b.BIL_BookingId='2' 
 GROUP BY b.BIL_Date 
 ORDER BY b.BIL_Date ASC
```

Comment: I get this error : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as BIL_Sum_Notcharged, sum(case when b.BIL_status = "charged" then s.STX_Amo' at line 16`.

Comment: Hum... Actually the sum for `2018-03-07` is equal to `210`. It should be `105`.

Comment: oups i overcomplicated it, now i tested it on the fiddle, sorry again for my mistake

Comment: Don't be sorry. You help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Daniel, sorry but I just remark that the query do not take care about the `BIL_Quantity` which is the quantity of thing charged / notcharged. Any luck, you can update your solution with this factor please?